# Could array.length be below 0 in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Since people are often using

```
array.length < 1
```

to check if an array is empty instead of

```
array.length === 0
```

I wonder if there are cases array.length could be below 0.

Comment: Your question is incomplete. Don't forget about rulling out fractional lengths, like 0.5 ;)

Comment: @missingno: I went ahead and answered that part, too. ;-)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

No, the `length` of an array is a non-negative integer. From [the spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ordinary-and-exotic-objects-behaviours.html#sec-array-exotic-objects):

> Every Array has a non-configurable "length" property whose value is always a **non-negative integral Number** whose mathematical value is less than 2^<sup>32</sup>.

*(my emphasis)*

So either check is perfectly fine, and both will have the same result for all arrays.

You may find people arguing for `=== 0` over `< 1` on the grounds of performance, because the [IsStrictlyEqual](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/abstract-operations.html#sec-isstrictlyequal) algorithm would take fewer steps than the [IsLessThan](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/abstract-operations.html#sec-islessthan) algorithm. Granted that's true, but I'm aware of no evidence that either is faster than the other in this use-case (and I've tested it; sadly the jsPerf test is gone now).  (Or others may argue that `<` will do type conversion and `===` won't, but that's irrelevant here; both types are the same.) But even if it were that one was minutely faster than the other, you'd have to be doing the comparison literally *billions* of times to see even the smallest real-world impact.