# check transaction exist in rxjs

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

```
 private transactions = new BehaviorSubject([]);
  

   getTransactions(): Observable<ITransaction[]> {

     return this.transactions.asObservable();

  }

checkTransactionsExist():Observable<boolean>  {
   
  return this.getTransactions().pipe(map((results:any) =>  results.length > 0 ? true));
     
} // i need to check data exist of transactions
```

But i am getting below error..What did i wrong please let me know

[image]

EROR:

1. **Argument of type 'unknown[]' is not assignable to parameter of type
   'OperatorFunction<ITransaction[], boolean>'.   Type 'unknown[]'
   provides no match for the signature '(source:
   Observable<ITransaction[]>): Observable'.**

EDIT: i need to check transactions  behavior subject array..i need return true if data exist or false

Comment: What if you do `map((results: ITransaction[])`?

Comment: Argument of type 'unknown[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<ITransaction[], boolean>'.
  Type 'unknown[]' provides no match for the signature '(source: Observable<ITransaction[]>): Observable<boolean>'.ts(2345)

Comment: Okay then also BehaviorSubject< ITransaction[]>([])

Comment: i need to check only true or false based on private transactions = new BehaviorSubject([]);

Comment: Yes, what if you add a type to `BehaviorSubject` also?

Comment: Argument of type 'unknown[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<ITransaction[], boolean>'.
  Type 'unknown[]' provides no match for the signature '(source: Observable<ITransaction[]>): Observable<boolean>'.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky same error i am getting

Comment: Shouldn't it be `results.length > 0 ? true : false`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following to help resolve this error. This is adding types and also updating the ternary statement which is invalid. It's invalid because you don't have the else condition. That being said, you can just simplify the return. `results.length > 0` is the same as `results.length > 0 ? true : false`:

```
private transactions = new BehaviorSubject<ITransaction[]>([]);

getTransactions(): Observable<ITransaction[]> {
  return this.transactions.asObservable();
}

checkTransactionsExist():Observable<boolean>  {
  return this.getTransactions().pipe(map((results:ITransaction[]) => results.length > 0));   
}
```

Comment: Thanks ..actually my mistake i have used jquery map instead of  rxjs..

Comment: If I need to promise<Boolean> what I need to to change?

Comment: @Glen I'd open up a new question for that.

Comment: @conor Without using to promise() method i.e directicly using behaviour subject is it possible?

Comment: myPromise().then(results => results.length > 0) or i guess from(myPromise()).pipe(map(results => results.length > 0))) maybe

Answer (score 1):

Start with the first error:

> ':' expected.(1005)

`results.length > 0 ? true` is invalid syntax: ternary expressions require the "else" part as well (e.g. `: something`).

If you are looking for a `true` or `false` value, `results.length > 0` is already that:

```js
  return this.getTransactions().pipe(map((results: any) => results.length > 0));
```

Note that `!!results.length` also returns a boolean and will produce the same effect as `results.length > 0` (since `results.length` will never be negative and `0` can be coerced as `false`). See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8190767/6789816) for performance notes.